# Is It possible to to see, edit or modify the available feature detector's code in OpenCV library?

Tags: android, opencv, augmented-reality

I am trying to implement a realtime object recognition application (Augmented Reality) in android phone using PyramidFAST(detector) + Freak(Descriptor) + BruteForce/FLANN matcher. Is it possible for me to see the real-coding of the detector and the descriptor inside the OpenCVforAndroid 2.4.6.0 library project? Is there any way to modify the code available in the library Project?

Comment: You sure can. Check out their [GitHub](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv) site.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I find opencv functions source code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17955167/how-can-i-find-opencv-functions-source-code)