# Where is OpenCV source code (.cpp) on Ubuntu?

Tags: opencv

I did not download and unzip OpenCV manually. Instead I relied on apt-get to install OpenCV.

The only place I can find are header files in `/usr/include/opencv2`

No link to OpenCV GitHub link please. It would be a pain later if it turns out that the code I am using on my PC is different from the one in GitHub.

I have looked at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17955167/how-can-i-find-opencv-functions-source-code) but I am not sure where OPENCV_HOME is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do a pkg-config:

```
pkg-config --cflags opencv
```

You will find the include files, header files like you give above. I think you are referring to cpp files. Since you downloaded with apt-get you dont have cpp files on your disk. You are going to face the github reality in this case. Just get the same version source code from github. But I dont think of any usage of source code besides compiling. If you want to search the source of a function just use the github web interface, it is easier and  a lot helpful